# Need help linking an ID column with another ID column for an insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm generating a dataset from a stored procedure. There's an `ID` column from a different database that I need to link to my dataset. Going from one database to the other isn't the issue. The problem is I'm having trouble linking an `ID` column that's in one database and not the other.

There's a common ID between the two columns: `CustomerEventID`. I know that'll be my link, but here's the issue. The `CustomerEventID` is a unique ID for whenever a customer purchases something in a single encounter.

The column I need to pull in is more discrete. It creates a unique ID (`CustomerPurchaseID`) for each item purchased from the encounter. However, I only need to pull in the `CustomerPurchaseID` for the last item purchased in that encounter. Unfortunately there's no time stamp associated with the `CustomerPurchaseID`.

It's basically like the `CustomerEventID` is a unique ID for a customer's receipt, whereas the `CustomerPurchaseID` is a unique ID for each item purchased on that receipt.

What would be the best way to pull the last `CustomerPurchaseID` from the `CustomerEventID` (I only need the last item on the receipt in my dataset)? I'll be taking my stored procedure with the dataset (from database A), using an SSIS package to put the dataset into a table on database B, then inserting the `CustomerPurchaseID` into that table.

I'm not sure if it helps, but here's the query from the stored procedure that will be sent to the other database (the process will run every 2 weeks to send it to Database B):

```
SELECT
    ce.CustomerEventID,
    ce.CustomerName,
    ce.CustomerPhone,
    ce.CustomerEventDate
FROM 
    CustomerEvent ce
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(d, ce.CustomerEventDate, GETDATE()) < 14
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this wall of text. :)

[image: Example]

Comment: Sorry, not entirely understand your issue here. Perhaps it would help if you can include some sample data and reference to that in describing your issue

Comment: @Squirrel thanks for the reply. I added an image of a table I created to the post to give you a visual of the ID-to-ID relationship. I hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CustomerPurchaseID` field is increasing (as you mentioned) then you can do `Order by Desc` on that field while picking up the line. This can be done using a sub-query in parent query or by doing a `Outer Apply` or `Cross Apply` if you need all the fields from `CustomerPurchase` table. Check below example.

```
declare @customerEvent table(CustomerEventID int not null primary key identity
                                , EventDate datetime)
declare @customerPurchase table(CustomerPurchaseID int not null primary key identity
                                , CustomerEventID int, ItemID varchar(100))

insert into @customerEvent(EventDate)
    values ('2018-01-01'), ('2018-01-02'), ('2018-01-03'), ('2018-01-04')
insert into @customerPurchase(CustomerEventID, ItemID)
    values (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)
            , (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 10)
            , (3, 1), (3, 2)
            , (4, 1)

-- if you want all the fields from CustomerPurchase Table
select  e.CustomerEventID
        , op.CustomerPurchaseID
from    @customerEvent as e
        outer apply (select top 1 p.* from @customerPurchase as p where p.CustomerEventID = e.CustomerEventID
                        order by CustomerPurchaseID desc) as op

-- if you want only the last CustomerPurchaseID from CustomerPurchase table
select  e.CustomerEventID
        , (select top 1 CustomerPurchaseID from @customerPurchase as p where p.CustomerEventID = e.CustomerEventID
                order by CustomerPurchaseID desc)
            as LastCustomerPurchaseID
from    @customerEvent as e
```

Comment: Wow... you knocked that one out of the park, so to speak. Thank you.